# Portfolio Website with thumbnails (designed with CSS), what is the best way to update my works?

Tags: html, css, portfolio

I am designing a website where I want to showcase my works with thumbnails (3 rows, 3 columns) that I will create in CSS. At the moment I am also looking into creating thumbnails out of sprites.

As I would like to be able to update my works every once in a while, what would be the best way to do it? I am sure there is something better out there than having to chance every thumbnail on every page of my site whenever I add or delete one work.

Is this something I should do in PHP? Or should I get into backend programming, or something else?

Comment: You just need a simple database, your web page grabs images and maybe some text from the database and outputs them. You insert into the database manually when you have a new work, and it will automatically update your page

Comment: Thanks Andy! Do you have any good link to get me started? I know a bit of programming and would like to learn a bit about database programming and managing.

Comment: I'll probably get lynched for this but I would recommend you learn the basics on w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp. This will introduce you to PHP/MySQL then you can go to other sites for further information

Comment: @Andy Every time someone uses MySQL, the Flying Spaghetti Monster kills a kitten.  MySQL is like a crippled version of PostgreSQL (or any other DBS, really).  If you're going to use a DB, you may as well do one that has a good feature set and doesn't have a reputation for losing your data.  You may think it doesn't matter now because you're just learning or your project is small, but you'll wish you hadn't started with MySQL when you realize you actually need the features it doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks Cimmanon, so which one should I learn instead?

Comment: @user1734386 Personally I'd look at PostgreSQL or SQL Server Express, depending on your platform.

Answer (score 4):

If your site is going to be fairly small, instead of having a database that stores your images, you could create an XML file that stores your image urls, attributes etc. The XML file could be your data source. **However, be careful this file doesn't get too big as it could become expensive on memory.**

Then you could create some code that is re-usable and loops through each node in the xml to display the images. Instead of putting your images on everypage.